# does $B'C + BC' = 1$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm studying Boolean algebra: I know this is a straightforward answer.
I'm a bit confused about if $B'C + BC'$ would be opposites in this case and would follow the rule that $A + A' = 1$ Or how can that simplify?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What are $A,B,C,A^\prime,B^\prime,C^\prime$?  Are these vectors or matrices?  Are the primes transposes?

Comment: No, try both equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks for feedback... I added Boolean algebra to the description

Comment: Oh.  Makes more sense!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to reduce $B'C + BC'$. However, you can see that $B'C + BC'$ is *not* equal to $1$. Try drawing a truth table for all values of $B$ and $C$.

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline B & C & B'C & BC' & B'C + BC' \\\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline\end{array}$$
> Does this remind you of a specific gate?

Answer (score 1):

If both $B$ and $C$ are true (or false) then the equation is false.

Indeed recall DeMorgan's law 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(B^{'} C)^{'} =B + C' \neq BC'.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$B \,\textrm{XOR}\, C = B'C + BC'$ is known as EXCLUSIVE OR.  This is true (equal to $1$) when only one of $B$ or $C$ are true.  If both or neither are true, than false (equal to $0$).